# Laravel API return 401 (Unauthorized) without Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, token

I create api token without passport.
First I added column `api_token` to `user` table. Next when user logged in I create new api token and save this token in DB.
Next I added to `api.php` code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function()  {
    Route::post('action', 'APIController@action');
});
```

Next I using axios to send data:

```
const api_token = '<?php echo $api_token ?>';
let options = {
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/action',
    data: data,
    headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
        },
}
let params = {
    'api_token': api_token
}

axios(options,params)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Next in `AuthServiceProvider.php` I added:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Auth::extend('token', function ($app, $name, array $config) {
        return new TokenGuard(Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']), $app->request);
    });
}
```

I using this [article](https://mydnic.be/post/super-easy-way-to-authenticate-an-api-user-in-your-laravel-application-without-using-laravel-passport).
Still I have error:

> 401 (Unauthorized)

***EDIT:***

I change my axios:

```
    const api_token = '<?php echo $api_token ?>';
    let options = {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/action',
        data: mergedData,
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
        },
        params: {
            'api_token': api_token
        }
    }
    axios(options)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Now I send token in GET, but I still have error:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/action?api_token=b005413b-3197-48ac-8747-32bbcf8b858f 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: No credentials needed?

Comment: @A.A. You mena send in header mail user ?

Comment: you could try with credentials, i know only 2 ways getting 401 1. no login 2. not same response headers -> but the 2nd one would deliever a different error
-> try it with authentication